# how to open a facebook dialog without blocked popup?

Tags: javascript, popup, facebook-login

I have a public domain with SSL conection. I added to my website facebook SDK for JavaScript. I try to do facebook auto login but it can avaible only after main login to system. The scenario is as follows: An user log in to the website. If he is logged on facebook, the profile img is loaded to the website but if he is not logged then on top the site he see facebook login button. On first I used FB.login but a browser blocks popup therefore I decided to use a button with onClick function but when I try run this function by clicking the button the popup is still blocked. Why?

Below is SDK:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : '{my-app-id}',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v3.3'
        });

      };

      (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

CheckLoginState function:

```
function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
      }
```

Button:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```

**I found a solution but somebody can tell me why it works but standard facebook button not?**

I change facebook button on my own button:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-material fb-login">Facebook login</button>
```

and I added a jquery handler to main.js

```
$('.fb-login').on('click', function(){
          FB.login(function(response){
                console.log(response)
              // Handle the response object, like in statusChangeCallback() in our demo
              // code.
            checkLoginState();
          });
      });
```

I opened a website, I ckliked on my button and I showing popup.

Comment: you did not add the relevant parts of your code. if the browser blocks it, you most likely do not use FB.login directly on user interaction.

Comment: for example I added this: <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button> and not working. Popup is still blocked.

Comment: that sounds like you may have some additional/aggressive blocker installed, maybe some adblocker?

Comment: I don't use additional software blocker. I use ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with default firefox browser and chrome. I see that on chrome now it's works but on firefox not, while on another website by the same firefox browser e.g. on stackoverflow login button/dialog works but on my public website not working. I don't any exception in settings. I don't know what it is problem?